# .htaccess custom redirect from subdirectory to root

Tags: html, regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a website (Wordpress) installed in the root HTTP folder. Everything works great.
I have another subdirectory which I want to make it a temporary default landing page (clean HTML5 website).

Currently, everything works great with the following rule:

```
# for subdirectory default landing
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[\s?]
RewriteRule ^$ /subdirectory [R=301,L]
# end rule for subdirectory

# begin WP
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# end WP
```

On the landing page, I have a link to the main website (targeted to www.domain.com/index.php), but when I click to that link, redirects me automatically back to my subdirectory (via .htaccess rule). There is any workaround?

Comment: I’m guessing that `www.domain.com/index.php` probably gets redirected back to `www.domain.com/` first, so that then `^$` matches again …? (Please verify whether that’s the case, using your browser dev tools network panel.) In that case, you’d have the problem that you want to treat two requests that look exactly same to the server, differently … Maybe adding a GET parameter to your link, and checking whether that is not set before you redirect into the subfolder, or something like that could help.